# Apache + mod_fcgid + perl = error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, perl, mod-fcgid

I'm trying to setup Apache2.2 with mod_fcgid and libapache2-mod-perl2 with no luck.

I've created a `fcgi-bin` directory in the root directory of my website and put there a `test.fcgi` file with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

print "This is test.fcgi!\n";
```

While trying to access it via `http://www.website.dom/fcgi-bin/test.fcgi` I get error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Here is my **vhost config**:

```
<VirtualHost 95.131.29.226:8080>
  ServerName website.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/data/website.com
  SuexecUserGroup user group 
  ServerAlias www.website.com
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml

  <Directory "/var/www/data/website.com/fcgi-bin/">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**fcgid.conf**:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  SocketPath /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock
  IdleTimeout 3600
  ProcessLifeTime 7200
  MaxProcessCount 8
  DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 2
  IPCConnectTimeout 8
  IPCCommTimeout 60
</IfModule>
```

**SuExec log**:

```
[2010-04-06 03:02:47]: uid: (500/equ) gid: (502/equ) cmd: test.fcgi
```

**Apache error log**:

```
test!
test!
[Tue Apr 06 03:02:51 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/data/website.com/fcgi-bin/test.fcgi(26267) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
[Tue Apr 06 03:02:53 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/data/website.com/fcgi-bin/test.fcgi(26261) exit(server exited), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
```

I've no clue why I'm getting error 500, but when I'm trying to access this file using console (`$ perl /var/www/data/website.com/fcgin-bin/test.fcgi`) everthing works fine without any errors...

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had to install Perl module for FastCGI with the following command:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install FCGI'
```

Comment: Not only install the module but also use it in your scripts. ;)
Remember: The FastCGI protocol is different from the CGI protocol and you can't just run your ordinary CGI scripts as FastCGI.